# error: '_' is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'

Tags: swift

Super new to Swift, so please bear with me.

I'm in the REPL, trying out what I thought was a simple data structure, the following:

```
var stuff = [
    [
        "id" : "A9AD6748-62A1-47E9-B0F7-2CF9B9C138EE",
        "label" : "My Cool Label",
        "things" : [
            "1st string",
            "2nd string",
            "3rd string"
        ]
    ],
    [
        "id" : "9C7882A7-E40C-421F-BEDB-8C0249A768E3",
        "label" : "Another Cool Label",
        "things" : [
            "4th string",
            "5th string",
            "6th string"
        ]
    ]
]
```

Swift complains about it in the following way:

```
repl.swift:72:13: error: '_' is not convertible to 'StringLiteralConvertible'
            "id" : "A9AD6748-62A1-47E9-B0F7-2CF9B9C138EE",
            ^~~~
repl.swift:70:17: error: type of expression is ambiguous without more context
    var stuff = [
                ^
```

I don't get it. There's no `_` in my code. Is the problem that I'm mixing types (strings and arrays)?

What is the right way to create this structure?

Comment: In this context, `_` refers to an unknown inferred type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess that the problem comes from mixing types in your dictionary is absolutely correct. The '`_`' that you're seeing refers to an unknown inferred type. Swift isn't able to figure out what type `stuff` is in your code, so you have to make things more clear for it.
The quick and dirty way to deal with this is to assert that your dictionary holds anything.

```
> let x = ["one": 1, "two": "2"]
repl.swift:7:27: error: '_' is not convertible to 'UnicodeScalarLiteralConvertible'
> let x : [String: Any] = ["one": 1, "two": "2"]
x: [String : Any] = 2 key/value pairs { ... }
```

The reason that Swift doesn't do this for you is that Swift won't ever infer the `Any` type, and for good reason. If it did that, it would make most type errors not appear. So you can force Swift to use the `Any` type if you want to...

But you probably shouldn't. If you're using `Any`, you lose out on quite a lot of type safety. The best way to handle this is to create an `enum` to hold the different types you want. This way you can constrain your list to only hold things you're expecting. If we define an enum like the following:

```
enum Thing {
    case AnInt(Int);
    case AString(String);
}
```

We can define a list that's only slightly more verbose, and Swift will be able to properly infer the type of the whole expression, and provide us more safety.

```
> let x = ["one": Thing.AnInt(1), "two": Thing.AString("2")]
x: [String : Thing] = 2 key/value pairs { ... }
```

Your example could use an enum like the this

```
enum ListOrString {
    case AString(String);
    case AList([String]);
}
```

And you could write your dictionary like this:

```
var stuff = [
    [
        "id" : ListOrString.AString("A9AD6748-62A1-47E9-B0F7-2CF9B9C138EE"),
        "label" : .AString("My Cool Label"),
        "things" : .AList([
            "1st string",
            "2nd string",
            "3rd string"
        ])
    ],
    [
        "id" : .AString("9C7882A7-E40C-421F-BEDB-8C0249A768E3"),
        "label" : .AString("Another Cool Label"),
        "things" : .AList([
            "4th string",
            "5th string",
            "6th string"
        ])
    ]
]
```

Note that you only have to specify `ListOrString` once, and that each other time you can just use a bare `.`. Typing this in, my Swift REPL correctly infers the type as

```
stuff: [[String : ListOrString]]
```

Comment: This is great! Typos: you go from `ListOrString` to `StringOrList`, also your `enum` needs `case` before each declaration. Otherwise, this is just what I needed to know. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, that's what I get for just retyping my REPL work instead of copy-pasting it.

Answer (score 0):

This is the "right" way to create such a data structure but you should try to make the type less ambiguous either by specifying the desired type or using structs to model it.

In a playground the type is inferred to be `[NSDictionary]` but you should rather use `[[String : AnyObject]]` in such a static language as Swift.

But neither type works in the REPL. So as workaround you can use `[[String : Any]]`. This is probably because it cannot infer bridged standard types.